# Why std::enable_if_t<is_object_task_v<std::remove_pointer_t<std::remove_reference_t<C>>>, bool> = true> not match

Tags: c++

i want define a function for special type,  use template sfinae

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


template <typename C>
constexpr bool is_object_task_v = std::is_base_of<Node, C>::value
                                || std::is_same<Node, C>::value;

template <typename C, typename DataType = std::remove_pointer_t<std::remove_reference_t<C>>,
    typename std::enable_if_t<is_object_task_v<DataType>, bool> = true>
void Emplace(C&& c) {
    std::cout << "Emplace 4" << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> n = std::make_shared<Node>();
    Emplace(n);
    return 0;
};
```

compiler report this error:

```
template_test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
template_test.cpp:71:14: error: no matching function for call to 'Emplace(std::shared_ptr<Node>&)'
   71 |     Emplace(n);
      |              ^
template_test.cpp:64:6: note: candidate: 'template<class C, class DataType, typename std::enable_if<is_object_task_v<DataType>, bool>::type <anonymous> > void Emplace(C&&)'
   64 | void Emplace(C&& c) {
      |      ^~~~~~~
template_test.cpp:64:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
template_test.cpp:63:67: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, bool>'
   63 |     typename std::enable_if_t<is_object_task_v<DataType>, bool> = true>
```

it Can be successful if using Node instead of std::shared_ptr

Comment: You cannot apply `remove_pointer_t` to the smart pointer type as the latter is not a raw pointer type.

Comment: 。。。 My mistake, I remembered it wrong